# Powershell script real-time monitoring via Windows Service

Tags: powershell

I'm using a script to monitor a file. When a pattern is detected, it will send an email to notify someone.

I am creating a Windows Service via NSSM.

My question is: How can I improve the performance of my script? I have to monitor a large log file during the day. a rolling log file (log1.log, then log2.log, then log3.log etc) main log file
is log.log.
The time between log file rotations in seconds. Rotation time is about 2-3 seconds. The log file size is about 20-30MB.

Script :

```
while( $true ) {

Start-Transcript -path c:\temp\monitor_file.log

$fromaddress = "filemon@contoso.com"
$emailto = "IT@contoso.com"
$SMTPSERVER = "xx.xx.xx.xx"

$File = "C:\temp\log.log"
Get-Content $File -Wait -Last 0 | Select-string  'Finished.' | ForEach {
    Send-mailmessage -from $fromaddress -to $emailto -subject "Log changed" -smtpServer $SMTPSERVER -Encoding UTF8 -Priority High
}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on the numbers in your question you need to change how you approach the problem. I dont have enough info from your question to give you the correct answer, but here are some ideas for different approaches that might suit your goals and will perform better.

1. If the log files are rotating every few seconds can you monitor the directory where the rotated files are created and then process each rotated file once?

   If you search for the dotnet class `System.IO.FileSystemWatcher` there are various tutorials on how to use this to trigger PowerShell in response to files being created.
2. Could you just run your script against the logs every X seconds/minutes? You can store the last time you checked, and look for all log files/lines since and process them as required.

   Task Scheduler is an easy way to implement this - but a powershell process will be launched each time which is a relatively expensive startup cost so dont do it too frequently.

   Powershell itself has the concepts of Tasks and the newer RunSpaces which allow much more control but its a lot more complicated than task scheduler.

Both of these options will increase the time it takes to send the emails, but massively reduce the number of times your code is executing - that is where you will see the performance benefit. You need to pick a suitable compromise based on your goals/data.

Your current solution will send emails very quickly after the string is found, but the cost is it will generate a great deal of overhead and may even be slowing down the process generating the log files/the machine itself.