# Powershell script to monitor a process with services

Tags: powershell, malware-detection

I'm noticing a system process is growing in memory size over the course of weeks and wondering what the powershell commands would be to write a script to monitor this and send me an email when the size increases by 1 Gig (or another size).

The process is

```
System Host: DCOM Server Process Launcher
  + System Events Broker
  + Power
  + Plug and Play
  + DCOM Server Process Launcher
  + Background Tasks Infrastructure Service
```

After 5 days the process size is 1,772.4 MB.  I was first alerted to it when the size was over 25 Gig and my system was running short of memory.

### Searching for a solution

- [Powershell script real-time monitoring via Windows Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75630642/powershell-script-real-time-monitoring-via-windows-service) - No answer, question too broad.
- https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/service-host-dcom-server-process-launcher-4-high/4517928a-7b18-46d7-bb2d-a36e810f413a - Same question but no answer.